# Use of "/xxxx.form" in the action attribute of form tag in HTML

Tags: html, forms, action, submission

Can someone help me understand how the submission of the form would be when the firm's action is "/userlogin.form"?

Will it call some form component on submission or how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an user goes to the form and click on Submit, the `http://www.your-domain.com/userlogin.form` file will be loaded with the form data.

For further information, look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp.

Comment: Thanks Nicolapps. This helps. Now, if my action is action="demo_form.asp" , does this mean the demo_form.asp sits on the same server from where my form page is loaded?

Comment: `/demo_form.asp` will load the demo_form.asp file at the root of your website, but you can use `action="http://www.otherdomain.com/my_form.asp"` too !